# Reduce Volume AWS EBS EC2 LVM Partition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lvm, amazon-ebs, dd

**Problem**

I have a physical machine with 1 TB disk and it was copied via command line *dd*, the disk was imported into S3 and successfully converted to AMI. But now I have a cost problem and I need to reduce this machine to 30 GB. I am looking for a solution on the internet but all tutorials found do not cite cases with lvm partitions.

**What i tried**

https://n2ws.com/blog/how-to-guides/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-an-ebs-volume

https://medium.com/@andtrott/how-to-downsize-a-root-ebs-volume-on-aws-ec2-amazon-linux-727c00148f61

https://medium.com/@rahulian/how-to-reduce-volume-of-an-aws-ec2-instance-d493ec891698

[How to reduce AWS EBS root volume size?](https://serverfault.com/questions/673048/how-to-reduce-aws-ebs-root-volume-size)

**Useful information**

SO: CENTOS 5.9

```
[root @] # fdisk -l

Disk / dev / hda: 1000.7 GB, 1000727379968 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors / track, 121664 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Boot Start End Blocks Id System Device
/ dev / hda1 * 1 13 104391 83 Linux
/ dev / hda2 14 121601 976655610 8e Linux LVM

[root @] # df -h
System File Us Usa Disp Usage% Mounted on
/ dev / mapper / VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      897G 4.4G 847G 1% /
/ dev / hda1 99M 17M 78M 18% / boot
tmpfs 501M 0 501M 0% / dev / shm
```

Comment: Rather than link to each thing you've tried, can you please list them and tell us why they didn't work for you. That will help us understand the problem better.

Comment: If you don't know enough to shrink an LVM partition, you are probably better off building a new machine and copying the appropriate data across.   Disk operations of this nature carry risk if you do know what you are doing, and if you don't can lead to a world of hurt.    If you decide to progress regardless, LVM works the same way regardless of the underlying provider - research how to shrink an LVM.

Comment: Guys first thank you very much for the answers, let's go by parts:
The error is simply EC2 does not start, no logging - I believe the error is because I did not create an lvm for copying, instead I created a primary partition and copied its contents to the other side without regard to /boot and swap, the next step was to copy the contents from one disk to another and change the label.
And about creating a new machine is out of the question because I do not have the original data in documentation to install applications, this machine is very old.